# Does potential energy increase inertial mass of system?

Tags: mass, mass-energy, inertia

For example, we have a ball with mass *m* lying on the Earth. Then we lift it to a height *h*. So, now system *Earth-ball* have potential energy $E_p = mgh$. From Mass–energy equivalence system got $mass = \frac{E_p}{c^2}$. Does it mean that potential energy increased  inertial mass of system and it's harder to accelerate that system, or potential energy just increased rest mass of system *Earth-ball*?

Answer (score 1):

If the energy to lift the ball came from outside of the Earth-ball system, then energy has been added to the system. And that means that the rest mass (energy) of the system has in fact increased.

Comment: Let me complete your argument. If instead it's you, staying on Earth, who lift a heavy rock, it's true that potential energy of rock-Earth system has increased, but at the expense of your internal energy. So total mass you-rock-Earth is unchanged.